# for loop not printing every row in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv

I have a pandas df that is extracted from a csv file that is being created like this

```
def recalc_stock_2day_rsi(ticker):
    output = open("output.csv", "a")
    yf.pdr_override()
    df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
    df_close_only = df['Close']
    try:
        rsi = calc_rsi(df_close_only, 2)
    except AttributeError:
        rsi = 100
    if rsi < 30:
        output.write(f"{ticker}\n")
    
   
    output.close()
```

and being turned into a csv using the
`dfcsv = pd.read_csv("output.csv")` and it looks like the following

```
    UPST
0    WMT
1   NFLX
2    EXC
4    AES
..   ...
63   TME
64   BSX
65  QCOM
66  GILD
67  ABNB
```

however for some reason whenever I try to run the command

```
for row in dfcsv:
        print(row)
```

it only prints out `UPST`

Comment: you can apply `iterrows()` in for loop. if you wanted indexes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for row in dfcsv` loop is only iterating over the columns of the dataframe, not the rows.
You can use the `iterrows()` method like this:
This will iterate over each row of the dataframe and print the row as a pandas series.

```
for index, row in dfcsv.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Or you can use this to print a specific column of the row:

```
for index, row in dfcsv.iterrows():
    print(row['column_name'])
```

Comment: since the "column_name" in this case is just the first element added to the csv it changes so i cant use t he second option but the first one worked perfectly thank you

Answer (score 0):

when you iterate over a dataframe with a for each loop, it loops through the columns:

```
for i in range(len(dfcsv)):
    print(dfcsv['UPST'][i])
```

or

```
for row in dfcsv['UPST']:
    print(row)
```